# Nextjs - aplication size over 2GB

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have frontend application in react.js (typescript). After build my dockerfile was size around 300 MB (including assets images).

Yesterday I add next.js to my application and application has size over 2GB. Now when I push image to my gitlab registry. It is anoying wait too long for docker push.

When I debug size of my project I found out:

- [image: node_modules folder] My node_modules folder has size 1GB
- And .next folder has 1.4 GB [image]

Now when I am using next.js I need node_modules folder. I expect there is no way to size optimalization.

And .next folder is needed too for production.

Is it some way how reduce size of my project?

Answer (score 0):

One optimisation you could make, albeit probably not major impact, is to only install the dependencies you actually need in your production environment. Carefully go through your dependencies and split the ones really only required on your dev machine into the "devDependencies" section of your package.json. Then in the Dockerfile (or alike) install the deps using the `npm install --production` command.

Dependencies related to testing, linting and so forth can be moved to dev.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install#:%7E:text=With%20the%20%2D%2Dproduction,use%20%2D%2Dproduction%3Dfalse